# How do you open the UNIX shell?

Tags: command-line

How do you open the unix shell or UNIX command-line shell on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

There is a keyboard shortcut that starts a Terminal session.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd>

Alternatively, press the `windows` button and type `Terminal`

Answer (score 1):

In the Desktop Environment start the program "Terminal" or press ctrl-alt-F2 (F1 to F6 is normally possible).

Answer (score 1):

1. Click the launcher [image]
2. Type terminal
3. Click the terminal app that is shown [image]
4. Start using the terminal window shown [image]

Answer (score 0):

You are likely looking to open a `terminal` which can be accomplished by opening your `dashboard/start menu` and typing `terminal` in the search bar.

As a point of context: The `shell` is less the window you enter commands into, and more the *environment* in which the commands are **interpreted**. There are a few different options as far as `shells` are concerned, the default and most widely used for Linux being `bash`. There is also however `tcsh` and just plain `sh`

Each has their own particular usage style as well as strengths and weaknesses.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the graphical terminal in any of the ways others have mentioned:

1. Click on the "start" button thing and type "terminal"
2. Hit the Windows key (aka Meta key) to open the command launcher, and type "terminal" or "gnome-terminal"
3. Open the start button thingy and browse through to find the terminal.

In addition to opening the graphical terminal, if you want to look really cool, type Ctrl+Alt+F1 to go to a TTY terminal. You're sure to get all the ladies if you know this cool trick

Ctrl+Alt+F7 will go back to graphics (or sometimes you need Ctrl+Alt+F8).